# Mysql Query Optimization

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing, innodb

I've got a table with close to 7 million rows in it. Here's the table structure

```
 `CREATE TABLE `ERS_SALES_TRANSACTIONS` (
  `saleId` int(12) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ERS_COMPANY_CODE` int(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `SALE_SECTION` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `SALE_DATE` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `SALE_STOCKAGE_EXACT` int(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `SALE_NET_AMOUNT` decimal(11,2) DEFAULT NULL, 
  `SALE_ABSOLUTE_CDATE` date DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`saleId`),
  KEY `index_location` (`ERS_COMPANY_CODE`),
  KEY `idx-erscode-salesec` (`SALE_SECTION`,`ERS_COMPANY_CODE`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `idx-saledate-section` (`SALE_DATE`,`SALE_SECTION`) USING BTREE
  KEY `idx_quick_sales_transactions` (`ERS_COMPANY_CODE`,`SALE_SECTION`,`SALE_DATE`,`SALE_STOCKAGE_EXACT`,`SALE_NET_AMOUNT`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

This query is taking more than 7 secs to execute, is there any way to speed this up?

```
SELECT 
   A.SALE_SECTION,  
   SUM(IF(A.SALE_DATE BETWEEN '2016-01-16' AND '2016-04-30'
          AND A.SALE_STOCKAGE_EXACT BETWEEN 0 AND 90, A.SALE_NET_AMOUNT, 0)) AS fs1_pd1_sale,
   SUM(IF(A.SALE_DATE BETWEEN '2016-01-16' AND '2016-04-30'
          AND A.SALE_STOCKAGE_EXACT BETWEEN 91 AND 180, A.SALE_NET_AMOUNT, 0)) AS fs2_pd1_sale,
   SUM(IF(A.SALE_DATE BETWEEN '2016-01-16' AND '2016-04-30'
          AND A.SALE_STOCKAGE_EXACT BETWEEN 181 AND 365, A.SALE_NET_AMOUNT, 0)) AS os1_pd1_sale,
   SUM(IF(A.SALE_DATE BETWEEN '2016-01-16' AND '2016-04-30'
          AND A.SALE_STOCKAGE_EXACT BETWEEN 366 AND 9999, A.SALE_NET_AMOUNT, 0)) AS os2_pd1_sale,
   SUM(IF(A.SALE_DATE BETWEEN '2016-01-16' AND '2016-04-30', A.SALE_NET_AMOUNT, 0)) AS TOTAL_PD1_SALE,
   SUM(IF(A.SALE_DATE BETWEEN '2016-04-01' AND '2016-04-30'
          AND A.SALE_STOCKAGE_EXACT BETWEEN 0 AND 90, A.SALE_NET_AMOUNT, 0)) AS fs1_pd2_sale,
   SUM(IF(A.SALE_DATE BETWEEN '2016-04-01' AND '2016-04-30'
          AND A.SALE_STOCKAGE_EXACT BETWEEN 91 AND 180, A.SALE_NET_AMOUNT, 0)) AS fs2_pd2_sale,
   SUM(IF(A.SALE_DATE BETWEEN '2016-04-01' AND '2016-04-30'
          AND A.SALE_STOCKAGE_EXACT BETWEEN 181 AND 365, A.SALE_NET_AMOUNT, 0)) AS os1_pd2_sale,
   SUM(IF(A.SALE_DATE BETWEEN '2016-04-01' AND '2016-04-30'
          AND A.SALE_STOCKAGE_EXACT BETWEEN 366 AND 9999, A.SALE_NET_AMOUNT, 0)) AS os2_pd2_sale,
   SUM(IF(A.SALE_DATE BETWEEN '2016-04-01' AND '2016-04-30', A.SALE_NET_AMOUNT, 0)) AS TOTAL_PD2_SALE,
   SUM(IF(A.SALE_DATE BETWEEN '2016-05-01' AND '2016-05-31'
          AND A.SALE_ABSOLUTE_CDATE BETWEEN '2016-03-01' AND '2016-05-31', A.SALE_NET_AMOUNT, 0)) AS fs1_achived_sale,
   SUM(IF(A.SALE_DATE BETWEEN '2016-05-01' AND '2016-05-31'
          AND A.SALE_ABSOLUTE_CDATE BETWEEN '2015-12-01' AND '2016-02-29', A.SALE_NET_AMOUNT, 0)) AS fs2_achived_sale,
   SUM(IF(A.SALE_DATE BETWEEN '2016-05-01' AND '2016-05-31'
          AND A.SALE_ABSOLUTE_CDATE BETWEEN '2015-06-01' AND '2015-11-30', A.SALE_NET_AMOUNT, 0)) AS os1_achived_sale,
   SUM(IF(A.SALE_DATE BETWEEN '2016-05-01' AND '2016-05-31'
          AND A.SALE_ABSOLUTE_CDATE BETWEEN '2006-12-26' AND '2015-05-31', A.SALE_NET_AMOUNT, 0)) AS os2_achived_sale,
   SUM(IF(A.SALE_DATE BETWEEN '2016-05-01' AND '2016-05-31', A.SALE_NET_AMOUNT, 0)) AS Total_ACHIVED_SALE
   FROM ERS_SALES_TRANSACTIONS A WHERE A.ERS_COMPANY_CODE = 48 GROUP BY A.SALE_SECTION
```

Here's Explain query

```
{
"data":
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "select_type": "SIMPLE",
        "table": "A",
        "type": "ref",
        "possible_keys": "index_location,idx-erscode-salesec,idx-saledate-section",
        "key": "index_location",
        "key_len": "5",
        "ref": "const",
        "rows": 1411944,
        "Extra": "Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort"
    }
]
}
```

After adding composite index, time decreased to 4.03 sec. Here' the plan

```
{
"data":
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "select_type": "SIMPLE",
        "table": "A",
        "type": "ref",
        "possible_keys": "index_location,idx-erscode-salesec,idx-saledate-section,idx_quick_sales_transactions",
        "key_len": "5",
        "key": "idx_quick_sales_transactions",
        "ref": "const",
        "rows": 1306058,
        "Extra": "Using where"
    }
]
```

}

Comment: Try and get rid of all those `SUM(IF(...`, try (outer) self joins instead.

Comment: key `index_location` is the index for ERS_COMPANY_CODE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't agree with Jimmy B here. Your query looks perfect in my opinion.

Depending on how many records there are for company 48 either the full table should be read sequentially (when it's many, say, 50% of all table records) or an index on ERS_COMPANY_CODE should be used (when it's not that many, say, only 1% of all records).

As the DBMS decided to use the index on ERS_COMPANY_CODE, the latter should be the case.

You can try to further speed up the query by creating a composed index. Make that at least `(ERS_COMPANY_CODE , SALE_SECTION)`, so as to have the `GROUP BY` quicker. Better even add all fields, so all data can be gathered from the index and the table itself doesn't have to be accessed any more.

```
CREATE INDEX idx_quick_sales_transactions ON ERS_SALES_TRANSACTIONS
  (ERS_COMPANY_CODE, SALE_SECTION, SALE_DATE, SALE_STOCKAGE_EXACT, SALE_NET_AMOUNT);
```

Comment: How to figure out the column order for composite index? if i need to do this for other queries

Comment: I always use columns in the order of 1. columns in `WHERE` clause, 2. columns in `GROUP BY` clause, 3. columns in `HAVING` clause, 4. columns in `SELECT` clause. So retrieving the data has first priority, aggregating second, and displaying results last.

Comment: Alright, i'll make a note of it. Thanks for the help

Comment: And I just notice that I neglected column `SALE_ABSOLUTE_CDATE` which is also in the `SELECT` clause. Add this to the index, so the index is completely covering the query data. (It's a very big index, but well, it gets access as fast as possible.)

Comment: okay but is there any order that i need to follow for SELECT clause columns?

Comment: No, I don't think so.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111522/discussion-between-sam-and-thorsten-kettner).

Comment: [_How to figure out column order for composite index_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql).

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if there is a way to speed this up.  But, you can try using an index.  I would recommend one on `ERS_SALES_TRANSACTIONS(ERS_COMPANY_CODE, SALE_SECTION, SALE_DATE, SALE_NET_AMOUNT)`.

This is a covering index for the query, meaning that all columns used for the query are in the index -- and hence the data base engine does not need to access the original data pages.

However, the performance still depends on the number of rows that match the particular company code.  And, in particular, the performance of the file sort used for aggregation.

Comment: Okay, after adding the composite index query time decreased to 4.03 sec but its still a lot

Comment: Do you have a table with one row per `ERS_COMPANY_CODE` and `SALE_SECTION` ?

Comment: How do you guys figured the column order for composite index? if i need to do this for other queries

Comment: `WHERE A.ERS_COMPANY_CODE = 48 GROUP BY A.SALE_SECTION` -- do the `WHERE =` column(s) first, then range(s), then `GROUP BY`.  See [_cookbook_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
   sales.SALE_SECTION,
   SUM( fs1_pd1.SALE_NET_AMOUNT ) AS fs1_pd1_sale,
   SUM( fs2_pd1.SALE_NET_AMOUNT ) AS fs2_pd1_sale,
...
FROM ERS_SALES_TRANSACTIONS sales

LEFT OUTER JOIN ERS_SALES_TRANSACTIONS fs1_pd1 ON sales.ERS_COMPANY_CODE = fs1_pd1.ERS_COMPANY_CODE AND sales.SALE_SECTION = fs1_pd1.SALE_SECTION
  AND fs1_pd1.SALE_DATE BETWEEN '2016-01-16' AND '2016-04-30'
  AND fs1_pd1.SALE_STOCKAGE_EXACT BETWEEN 0 AND 90

LEFT OUTER JOIN ERS_SALES_TRANSACTIONS fs2_pd1 ON sales.ERS_COMPANY_CODE = fs2_pd1.ERS_COMPANY_CODE AND sales.SALE_SECTION = fs2_pd1.SALE_SECTION
  AND fs2_pd1.SALE_DATE BETWEEN '2016-01-16' AND '2016-04-30'
  AND fs2_pd1.SALE_STOCKAGE_EXACT BETWEEN 91 AND 180
...
   WHERE sales.ERS_COMPANY_CODE = 48
   GROUP BY sales.SALE_SECTION
```

This way, the optimizer can use more than one index for the query.

I suggest, however, to first try the composite index @Thorsten Kettner recommends as that may work out to the same effect with much less complexity.

Comment: Sorry, this query taking more time than my query time. Tested with before and after adding covering index